# Restricted IAM policy for DELETE action on API Gateway Deployment resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I had created a serverless user with necessary permissions to create and deploy AWS lambda function along with API Gateway.

However when I change a piece of code and do `serverless deploy` on it gives the error:

```
Error:
DELETE_FAILED:... "User: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:user/serverless is not authorized to perform: apigateway:DELETE on resource: arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/1zhmt1r45r2/deployments/27gb11 because no identity-based policy allows the apigateway:DELETE action (Service: ApiGateway, Status Code: 403...
```

Now I can go ahead and add DELETE action permission on apigateway resource. **But** giving permission to delete any apigateway respource on a production environment is way too risky. What I want is to restrict what this serverless/progammatic user can delete (Only the apis created by the itself, or prefix on resource name).

I have created policies to only allow serverless-user to create resources with specific *prefix*, but since this error shows error on resource `arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1::/restapis/1zhmt1r45r2/deployments/27gb11` where it is using *ids* (`1zhmt1r45r2/deployments/27gb11`). I can't think of a way to effectively restrict what this user can delete.

Is there any work-around? I need to figure this out quite urgently.

Comment: I dont understand if I am blocked from stackoverflow, or it has become less active community. Earlier a question would get atleast a comment within 30 min. And now even though questions I ask I try my best to be comprehensive, most of them go without any comment or answer. Its really a sad thing for me

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you really want to achieve whithout having more details, but the error you have is telling you need to grant `apigateway:DELETE` permission to your lambda function using a policy that is restricted only to your lambda function. The easiest way to do this is specifying it in a SAM template. This way you can implement your IaC (Infrastructure as code) without manual process and allows you to automate the process for redeployments and adding the template to source control. The following example defines a lambda function which needs `apigateway:DELETE` permission

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Resources:
role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs"
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: prod
  CreateLedger:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: CreateLedgerFunction
      Handler: QLDB.API.Config.Lambda::QLDB.API.Config.Lambda.Functions.CreateLedger.CreateLedgerFunction::FunctionHandler
      Runtime: dotnetcore3.1
      Timeout: 30
      CodeUri: .
      Policies:
        - Statement:
          - Sid: QLDBCreateLedgerCommandPolicy
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - apigateway:DELETE #<----- specify the permissions
            Resource: '*'
      Events:
        CreateLedger:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /createLedger
            Method: post
            RestApiId:
              Ref: ApiGatewayApi
```